# Creating a Javascript form to obtain User input

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, submit

I have the following code:

```
var stereo_form =new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            id: "stereoInfo_panel",
            autoDestroy:true,
            frame: true,
            width: 410,
            items:[{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'DEM Resolution',
            name: 'resolution'

        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Matching Level',
            name: 'matching'

        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Size of DEM',
            name: 'size'

        }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Confirm',
                handler: function(){//HELP ME!
                }
        }]
    }); 

    var w =new Ext.Window({
        id: "stereoInfo_win",
        title: "Stereo Reconstruction Parameters",
        layout: 'form',
        height: 160,
        width: 350,
        items: stereo_form

    });

w.show();
w.focus();
```

3 problems:

1. I want the rest of the script to pause running while this form is displayed until the button is pressed.
2. When the button is pressed I want the form to be destroyed.
3. When the button is pressed I want the 3 values to be passed to variables.

Can anyone help?

P.S. I just want the values to be assigned to global variables, not to a server-side file...

Comment: Just want the values to be assigned to a global variable, no server side file required......

Comment: what do you mean by saying "the script should be paused while showing the form". You can render the Ext window modal. Can you post the rest of the script that should be paused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by creating a form with associated window and buttons as follows:

```
var stereo_form =new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        id: "stereoInfo_panel",
        autoDestroy:true,
        labelWidth: 300,
        frame: true,
        width: 515,
        items:[{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'DEM Resolution (Enter between 0.002 - 0.1 metres)',
            name: 'resolution',
            regex: /^0[.](1|0[1-9][0-9]*|00[2-9][0-9]*)$/,
            regexText: 'Only values between 0.002 - 0.1 allowed',
            value: '0.005' //sets a default value

        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Pyramid Level (Enter either 0 or 1)',
            regex: /^[0-1]$/,
            regexText: 'Only values of 0 or 1 allowed',
            name: 'matching',
            value: '0' //sets a default value

        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Size of DEM (Enter between 0 - 50.00 metres)',
            name: 'size',
            value: '20.00' //sets a default value

        }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Confirm',
                handler: function()
                        {
                        var values = stereo_form.getForm().getValues();
                        res = values.resolution;
                        pyramid = values.matching;
                        distance = values.size;
                        user1 = "Resolution of DEM in X and Y directions (metres) = " + res;
                        user2 = "Minimum (biggest) image pyramid level for matching (one level = img/2) = " + pyramid;
                        user3 = "Maximum distance from camera to be reconstructed - Cartesian DEM only (metres) = " + distance;
                        loadXMLDoc("/stereo_proc4.php?left="+leftrel_safe+"&right="+rightrel_safe+"&res="+res+"&pyramid="+pyramid+"&distance="+distance,state_Change);
                        w.close();
                        }

        }]
    }); 

    var w =new Ext.Window({
        id: "stereoInfo_win",
        title: "Stereo Reconstruction Parameters",
        layout: 'form',
        height: 152,
        width: 515,
        items: stereo_form

    });

w.show();
w.focus();
```